# Как поменять содержимое окна?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3, pysimplegui

Есть код на PySimpleGUI, всё хорошо, но не могу понять как менять содержимое окон. Подскажите, пожалуйста на данном примере:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import sqlite3
class DB:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute(
            '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student
            (id integer primary key, fa text, im text, ot text)''')
        self.conn.commit()

    def insert(fa,im,ot):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(
            '''INSERT INTO student (fa,im,ot)
            VALUES (?,?,?)''',
        (fa,im,ot))
        conn.commit()

sg.theme('Topanga')

layout =[[sg.Text('Фамилия:', size=(30,1),justification='right'),sg.InputText(key='-FAM-', do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text('Имя:', size=(30,1),justification='right'),sg.InputText(key='-NAME-', do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text('Отчество:', size=(30,1),justification= 'right'),sg.InputText(key='-OT-', do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Submit('Запись'),sg.Cancel('Поменять1')]]

layout2=[[sg.Text('ФИО:', size=(30,1),justification='right'),sg.InputText(key='-FAM-', do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text('Номер:', size=(30,1),justification='right'),sg.InputText(key='-NAME-', do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text('Серия:', size=(30,1),justification= 'right'),sg.InputText(key='-OT-', do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Submit('Добавить'),sg.Cancel('Поменять2')]]

window = sg.Window('Форма ввода').Layout(layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None:
        break
    if event == 'Запись':
        fa = values['-FAM-']
        im = values['-NAME-']
        ot = values['-OT-']
        DB.insert(fa,im,ot)
    if event == 'Поменять1':
        window = sg.Window('Форма ввода').Layout(layout2) #Меняет содержимое окна, но только один раз
    if event == 'Поменять2':
        window = sg.Window('Форма ввода').Layout(layout) #Выводит ошибку при нажатии на кнопку
```

Comment: `PySimpleGui` — это "левая" библиотека, на ней особо ничего не пишут. Советую посмотреть в сторону `PyQt5`. `Tkinter` тоже неплохо, но `PyQt5` лучше.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, я знаю что такие существуют, Tkinter уже освоил более менее, PyQT5 вроде слышал что платная, ещё знаю о kivy. Но пока на этой, т.к. это тот же Tkinter(вроде как), но легче писать и быстрее. Потом kivy буду осваивать

Comment: Qt — платная, а PyQt5 — бесплатная: `pip3 install PyQt5` . Киви _ненавижу_ и не рекомендую.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, чуть позже гляну. Пока хочу с этой разобраться)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, можете сктнуть ссылку чем отличается QT от PyQT5?

Comment: PyQt - это обертка над бинарными библиотеками Qt. Сама Qt платная, если нужна поддержка, дополнительные инструменты и т.д. Без этого можно использовать бесплатно Qt в том числе и в закрытых проектах (с некоторыми ограничениями, некоторые модули распространяются только по лицензии GPL). См. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)#Licensing